# Difference between various classes to read a file

Tags: java

Can any one explain me the difference/when to use various classes to read a file in java. Like, Scanner vs FileInputStream etc..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was seriously asking myself the same question today, and you asked it here! +1

Comment: I asked myself the same question and went and looked it up -1

Comment: If you read the documentation, it may lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class **DataInputStream**
A data input stream is use to read primitive Java data types from an underlying input stream in a machine-independent way. An application uses a data output stream to write data that can later be read by a data input stream.
Data input streams and data output streams represent Unicode strings in a format that is a slight modification of UTF-8.

Class **BufferedReader**
Read text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.
The buffer size may be specified, or the default size may be used. The default is large enough for most purposes.
In general, each read request made of a Reader causes a corresponding read request to be made of the underlying character or byte stream.

Class **Scanner**
The Scanner class is used only for reading, not for writing, it allows reading files in a compact way.

hope it helps you